# I want to read NFC only when I click on the button

Tags: android, nfc

I followed this [link](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/reading-nfc-tags-with-android--mobile-17278) to read `NFC` from the tags and I am success with that, but the problem is, I want to read `NFC` only when I click the button. So in on new Intent I did this

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    /**
     * This method gets called, when a new Intent gets associated with the current activity instance.
     * Instead of creating a new activity, onNewIntent will be called. For more information have a look
     * at the documentation.
     *
     * In our case this method gets called, when the user attaches a Tag to the device.
     */
    readTag.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            bottomNavigationItemNFC.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            handleIntent(intent);
        }
    });

}
```

but still it is reading `NFC` tag before I click the button.

This is me firsttime posting question please excuse me if there are any mistakes. ThankYou

Comment: user this line  `adapter.enableForegroundDispatch(activity, pendingIntent, filters, techList);` in you `readTag.setOnClickListener()`

Comment: @SaurabhBhandari do you want me to remove `handleIntent(intent);` this line and replace what u said? and it is not working

Comment: put your listener in onCreate  not in onNewintent()

Comment: @SaurabhBhandari Not working after i click the button. It is still working before I click on the button

Comment: because you already enabled it in setupForgroundDispatch() method. don't enbal it in that method comment that line

Comment: wow! now it is working dude. Thank you